# Need a completion block for SnapKit constraints in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a UIView in swift using SnapKit to layout it's views. I want to blur one of the views, but I need to put the blur code in a method that runs AFTER all the layout code is finished and that one view has it's proper size.

I can't seem to figure out the right place for that blur code to go. Since snapkit is all based on blocks, it's all asynchronous and I don't know when it will be finished. What callback method can I use?

EDIT: I reported an [issue on SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/issues/187) and they say the blocks are synchronous after all. However, in `layoutSubviews` (and after the synchronous blocks) my frames are all still `CGRectZero`, so the blur code can't snapshot and blur a view of 0 width or height.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know SnapKit but there's a technique you can use to get code executed after the last of a bunch of asynchronous blocks has been completed.

The trick is to create a class to hold you piece of code and have each block hold a reference to it.  In the class's deinit code, you execute your code.

Example:

```
class CompletionBlock
{
   var completionCode:()->()

   init?(_ execute:()->() )
   { completionCode = execute }

   func deferred() {}

   deinit
   { completionCode() }
}
```

before calling the functions with run blocks, assign a variable with an instance of CompletionBlock and in each block add a call to its deferred() function.  Then set you variable to nil (or let it go out of scope from the calling function)

```
// ... 
var completion = CompletionBlock({ print("finished") })

doThis(completion: {
                     // ... whatever stuff you need to do
                     completion.deferred()
                   })

doThat(completion: {
                     // ... whatever stuff you need to do
                     completion.deferred()
                   })

completion = nil
// ....
```

The completion variable will be captured by the two blocks so there will be a reference to it (maintaining it active) until both blocks go out of scope.  The completion variable will then go out of scope itself and its deinit function will be called, execution your completion block at that time.

This may or may not help in your specific situation but I figured I throw it in, just in case.

Comment: This is an awesome idea!! However, it unfortunately doesn't work for this issue. I tried it and the view I want to blur is still of 0 width and height by the time the callback comes around, I think there's something else going on here.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps (if the layoutSubviews approach isn't working...) you could use something like a [dispatch group](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/), to ensure the constraints have been installed. Though this would be sort of unnecessary, if what they say is true.